# Distribution and density function of a point on the positive quadrant of a circle

Tags: probability

Consider the positive quadrant of a circle of radius 1

$$C=\{(x,y)| x>0, y>0, x^2+y^2<1 \}$$

I want to calculate the density and distribution functions of the polar coordinates $(\rho, \theta)$ of a point $P$ chosen at random in $C$.

Since the probability is uniform, the density function is $f(x,y)=4/\pi$, and the jacobian of the change of coordinates is $\rho$.

Therefore the density function of the polar coordinates is $g(\rho, \theta)=4\rho /\pi$.

Considering the circular sector formed by the radious $\rho$ and the angle $\theta$, I think the distribution function should be $G(\rho, \theta)=\pi \rho^2 \times \theta /2\pi =\theta \rho^2 /2$. But derivation gives $g(\rho, \theta)=\rho $, which is inconsistent with the above.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you calculated is the area of the circular segment. You have to divide it by the total area of the quadrant of the circle which is $\pi/4$ to get the probability of the point to fall in that area.